# AVFoundation PhotoApp - Can't get the flash working before the image saves in the library

Tags: ios, xcode, camera, swift3, avfoundation

before i post my entire code of my viewControllor that controls the main view of my cameraApp, i'll tell you what happens, what works and what don't ATM. The buttons for snapping the photo and saving it, for changing the cameras (front/back), setting the flash from auto/off. There are other things in this code that are for now set up but unused, but i don't think that they are causing this problem, i think that my ingnorance is the main problem. What i want to achieve through the help of you guys is that when i press the cameraButton, if the flash is set to auto, the app use the flash if needed and then saves the picture. I hope that someone can help me, the apple documents tell you all of the commands, but not where to put them in a easy way. Thanks in advance, here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import PageMenu


class randomController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate, CAPSPageMenuDelegate, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet weak var cameraPreview: UIImageView!


    @IBAction func cameraButton(_ sender: Any) {

        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
        let previewFormat = [
            kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
            kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160,
            kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160
                ]
        let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
        if (device?.hasTorch)! {
            do {
                print("diosotterrato")
                try device?.lockForConfiguration()
                //device?.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.on
                // device?.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.Off
                device?.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.auto
                device?.unlockForConfiguration()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }



        settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat
        sessionOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)

    }


    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundMarrone: UIImageView!

    func askPermission() {
        print("here")
        let cameraPermissionStatus =  AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

        switch cameraPermissionStatus {
        case .authorized:
            print("Already Authorized")
        case .denied:
            print("denied")

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry :(" , message: "But  could you please grant permission for camera within device settings",  preferredStyle: .alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel,  handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(action)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        case .restricted:
            print("restricted")
        default:
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, completionHandler: {
                [weak self]
                (granted :Bool) -> Void in

                if granted == true {
                    // User granted
                    print("User granted")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(){
                        //Do smth that you need in main thread
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // User Rejected
                    print("User Rejected")

                    DispatchQueue.main.async(){
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "WHY?" , message:  "Camera it is the main feature of our application", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                        alert.addAction(action)
                        self?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)  
                    } 
                }
            });
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var cameracapture: UIImageView!
    var pageMenu : CAPSPageMenu?

    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession();
    var sessionOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput();
    var sessionOutputSetting = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]);
    var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer();


    var flashButton = UIButton()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                pageMenu?.delegate = self

        var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = []

        backgroundMarrone.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:(view.frame.maxY/10*5), width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height )

        cameraPreview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: backgroundMarrone.frame.minY  )


            let switchCameraButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: cameraPreview.frame.maxY/12*9.8, width: 50, height: 50))
            switchCameraButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 100.0/255.0, green: 39.0/255.0, blue: 87.0/255.0, alpha: 0.0)
            switchCameraButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            switchCameraButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "btn_reverse_camera copy.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            self.view.addSubview(switchCameraButton)

            flashButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: cameraPreview.frame.maxX - 55, y: cameraPreview.frame.maxY/12*9.8, width: 50, height: 50))
            flashButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 100.0/255.0, green: 39.0/255.0, blue: 87.0/255.0, alpha: 0.0)
            flashButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton1(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            flashButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "btn_flash copy.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            self.view.addSubview(flashButton)




        let libraryController : UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "libraryController") as! libraryController
            libraryController.title = "Libreria"
            controllerArray.append(libraryController)


            let photoController : UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "photoController") as! photoController
            photoController.title = "Foto"
            controllerArray.append(photoController)



        let videoController : UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "videoController") as! videoController
        videoController.title = "Video"
        controllerArray.append(videoController)

        let parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
            .menuItemSeparatorWidth(0),
            .useMenuLikeSegmentedControl(true),
            .menuItemSeparatorPercentageHeight(0.1),
            .centerMenuItems (true)
        ]

        pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: cameraPreview.frame.maxY , width: self.view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height ), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

        self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)

        }
var ciaone = false



    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInDualCamera, AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInTelephotoCamera,AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.unspecified)




        for device in (deviceDiscoverySession?.devices)! {


            print("tipo di device: \(device.position)")

            if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front){
                do{

                    let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
                    if(captureSession.canAddInput(input)){
                        captureSession.addInput(input);
                        captureSession.startRunning()
                        print("entrato1")

                        if(captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput)){
                            captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput);
                            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession);
                            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
                            previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait;
                            cameraPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer);
                        print("entrato2")
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch{
                   print("exception!");
                }

            }

        }

        }


    func beginSession(captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?) {

        ciaone = false

        if captureSession.isRunning {
            captureSession.beginConfiguration()

            let currentInput : AVCaptureInput = captureSession.inputs[0] as! AVCaptureInput
            captureSession.removeInput(currentInput)

            do {
                try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
            } catch {
                print("Error adding video input device")
            }

            captureSession.commitConfiguration()

        } else {
            // Setup the camera and layer for the first time.
            do {
                try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
            } catch {
                print("Error adding video input device")
            }


            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            self.view.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, at: 0)
            previewLayer.frame = cameraPreview.bounds
            captureSession.startRunning()


        }
    }



    func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {

        if let error = error {
            print("error occure : \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        if  let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer,
            let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer,
            let dataImage =  AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer:  sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {
            print(UIImage(data: dataImage)?.size as Any)

            let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: dataImage as CFData)
            let cgImageRef: CGImage! = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)
            let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, nil, nil)
            self.cameracapture.image = image
        } else {
            print("some error here")
        }
    }

    var a = 0
    func pressButton(button: UIButton) {

        if (a == 0) {
            print("dioschifoso!")
            beginSession(captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo))

            a = 1

        } else {

            beginSession(captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.front))


            a = 0

        }
    }
    var flash = 0




    func toggleTorch(on: Bool) {
        //guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) else { return }
        /*
        if device.hasTorch {
            do {
                try device.lockForConfiguration()

                if on == true {
                    device.torchMode = .on
                } else {
                    device.torchMode = .off
                }

                device.unlockForConfiguration()
            } catch {
                print("Torch could not be used")
            }
        } else {
            print("Torch is not available")
        }
 */

    }

    func pressButton1(button: UIButton) {

        let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
        if (device?.hasTorch)! {
            do {
                try device?.lockForConfiguration()
                //device?.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.on
                // device?.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.Off
                device?.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.off
                device?.unlockForConfiguration()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        if (a == 0) {

            let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
            if (device?.hasTorch)! {
                do {
                    try device?.lockForConfiguration()
                    device?.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.auto
                   // device?.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.Off
                    //device?.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.auto
                    device?.unlockForConfiguration()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            //toggleTorch(on: true)
            flashButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "btn_flash_off.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)


            a = 1

        } else {


            //toggleTorch(on: false)
            flashButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "btn_flash copy.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            a = 0

        }


    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        previewLayer.frame = cameraPreview.bounds
    }



    func capturePicture(){


        }






    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0 and Xcode >= 8**

```
  @IBAction func flashTapped() {
    // check if flashlight available
        let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
        if (device?.hasTorch)! && (device?.hasFlash)! {
            do {
                try device?.lockForConfiguration()
            } catch {
                // handle error
                return
            }
            if device?.torchMode == .auto {
                device?.torchMode = .on
                device?.flashMode = .on
            }
            else if device?.torchMode == .on {
                device?.torchMode = .off
                device?.flashMode = .off
            }
            else {
                device?.torchMode = .auto
                device?.flashMode = .auto
            }

            device?.unlockForConfiguration()
        }
}
```

Comment: I'll integrate this code in a few minutes, i'll report back then! Thanks by the way for the help :)

Comment: implemented it, but it gives me a lot of errors, the biggest one happens in the device.lock configuration, xcode tells me "argument passed to call that takes no argument". Other than this, lots of optional type unwrapped.

Comment: Thanks, iOS 10 deprecated the .flashmode, changed it with AVCapturePhotoSettings.flashMode , how can i implement it?

Comment: Also, i tried your updated code, it works but when i capture the photo, if it's set to auto, in a dark room for example, it doesn't use the flash .I don't understand why :(

Comment: First tried with flash mode = on and check in a dark room working ?

Comment: Yes, with the flash mode = on, the flash worked, i pressed the button and it took the picture with the flash activated, deactivating it after i pressed it though. In auto, no flash in dark enviroment, it's like a specific line of code is needed to check the enviroment. I can't get my head around

Comment: okay. Put your phone on note book and flash = auto and tried to capture photo flash working?

Comment: Tried, as before in a dark room, the camera sees pitch black but doens't use the flash :(

Comment: Tried this "Put your phone on note book and flash = auto and tried to capture photo flash working?" yes or no?

Comment: Before you attempt to set properties of a capture device (its focus mode, exposure mode, and so on), you must first acquire a lock on the device using the lockForConfiguration: method. You can then set the properties and release the lock using the unlockForConfiguration method.

Comment: Read that line in the apple guide, don't know how and what to configure in it though, you know how?

Comment: [device setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus];

Comment: So if i put this exact line of code under the lockForConfiguration, it will solve my problem?

Comment: yes write in lockForConfiguration and unlock between

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/jwhX0 this is what xcode tells me, it expect also a ; separator after device

Comment: device?.focusMode = .continuousAutoFocus

Comment: Still doesn't work my friend. As before, if i set it to on, it stays on until i press che capture button, if i set it to auto, if i press the capture button on a notebook o in a dark room the flash doesn't turn on automaticaly